# Kinematics textbook illustration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

I have trouble interpreting this illustration. I see why **r** (position) and **a** (acceleration) are the way they are, but what happened to **v**? Why is it smaller than its coordinates? Is this another error in my textbook?

Comment: They just wanted to save space, so they drew $\vec v$ as one half of the $\vec v$ they indicated beneath the picture. In the real world, $\vec r$, $\vec v$, and $\vec a$ have different dimensions (units) so one shouldn't draw them to the "same graph" without specifying a convention. They just happened to choose an anomalously different convention for the velocities - by a factor of two.

Comment: Indeed, Lubos is right. The textbook isn't exactly "wrong," but that's definitely not a great diagram.

Comment: Note that the units of velocity are m/s and those of acceleration are m/s^2, so even the acceleration vector with the "right" length doesn't really fit with the axises. The decision is arbitrary, though a little silly.

Comment: @noname, What textbook is this?

Comment: Alvin Hudson, Rex Nelson - University Physics. But I shouldn't be too harsh on it. This book has actually made me love Physics, the explanations are usually crystal clear. Also, most of the errors introduced during the translation to Hungarian. So, the book is awesome.

Comment: Actually, I would fault the diagram for making it look like there is some sort of relation between the lengths of position, velocity and acceleration vectors.  Is noted in earlier comments, since the units are different, the relative lengths of the vectors mean nothing.  Only the directions are important.  That the book led you to think that the r and a vectors "made sense" is to me a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the units of the vectors are different, there is no need for the scales to be the same. Each physical quantity can have a different scale in the diagram.